# Removing OneDrive Without Adminstrator Rights

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I am using a virtual remote desktop.

On advice from IT, I activated OneDrive.  But using it with ArcGIS has been a nightmare.

I have followed the instructions to [Turn Off, Disable or Uninstall OneDrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-off-disable-or-uninstall-onedrive-f32a17ce-3336-40fe-9c38-6efb09f944b0?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#:%7E:text=Open%20File%20Explorer%2C%20right%2Dclick,More%20and%20select%20Quit%20OneDrive.) but I cannot uninstall it.  I can unlink it.

But OneDrive still has hold of my Documents folder.  When you check Properties on an ArcGIS folder that should be in my local, C:\Users\etc\Documents, it still has OneDrive in the path and performance is still terrible.

Can I remove OneDrive's clutch on my Documents folder without Admin privileges?

Comment: OneDrive is installed per user, meaning you can simply uninstall it from your user account without affecting any other users or the system in general. Just go in to add/remove programs and uninstall it. It doesn’t matter if your documents folder is still located in the OneDrive folder. You can move the documents folder wherever you want by changing the “location” of this special folder in its properties, which is typically in `C:\Users\<username>`. Location is not your problem. If you are having trouble with the linked instructions you need to [edit] your post and improve your question.

Comment: @Appleoddity, not having trouble with the linked instructions (except that the unlink doesn't persist from session to session).  But I get "Enter an admin user name and password. The requested operation requires elevation" from the uninstall.  Also, can you say more about changing the folder location? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Ah, I think I found it.  The Location tab on Properties has an editable field.  Thanks!